# Spaces converting to '+' from HTML form

Tags: html, forms, email, mailto

So I've been playing around with HTML forms and I am kind of new you all of this so any help would go a long way! But anyway... This is my form coding for emailing.

[image]
[image]

So when I submit that form with the correct areas filled, it then opens
in Outlook (2010 If that matters) were it then converts the spaces in the
body of the email into '+' (Plus symbols)... Can anyone give me ideas?
This HTML will be used on an offline site within our network and will not
go live. All computers are on the domain and will have access to this 
HTML link on there desktop.

Answer (score 3):

You should set the `enctype` attribute of the `<form>` tag to text.

```
<form enctype="text/plain" ...
```

More details in [this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279460)

> In both cases, the FORM data is e-mailed in as an Attachment, in an encoded format. For instance, in the preceding case, this is how the data looks:
>
> ```
> Subject=Test+Subject&Body=%09kfdskfdksfkds%0D%0A%09
> ```
>
> This is because the default ENCTYPE attribute for the FORM element is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". To e-mail data in > plain-text format instead, explicitly specify an ENCTYPE attribute of "text/plain". For instance:
>
> ```
> <FORM Action="mailto:xyz" METHOD="POST" ENCTYPE="text/plain">
>     mailto: protocol test:
>     <Br>Subject: 
>     <INPUT name="Subject" value="Test Subject">
>     <Br>Body:&#xa0;
>     <TEXTAREA name="Body">
>     kfdskfdksfkds
>     </TEXTAREA>
>     <BR>
>     <INPUT type="submit" value="Submit"> 
> </FORM>
> ```
>
> produces the following Body:
>
> ```
> Subject=Test Subject
> Body=   kfdskfdksfkds
> ```

Comment: But the subject doesn't get passed to the mail client so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `%20` for spaces in `mailto` links. I think you need to convert the `+` to spaces before you open the `mailto` link.