# I'm trying to auto-populate an email form using HTML only

Tags: html, enctype

Everything looks fine except for the body part.  If a user enters "Grab a beer with you", the body of the email would show "Grab+a+beer+with+you".  How do I get the body to be just a space instead of a +.  I'm also confused on what I should be using, some places say it should be a POST, but GET works, POST doesn't.  Anyways, here is my code.

```
<form enctype="text/plain" method="GET" action="mailto:{rudyg@hotmail.com}?subject=Subject&body=Body">

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleSelect1">What is this in regards to?</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1" name="subject" value="Subject">
            <option value="Job&nbsp;opportunity">Job opportunity</option>
            <option value="Question&nbsp;about&nbsp;myself&nbsp;or&nbsp;my&nbsp;code">Question about myself or my code</option>
            <option value="General&nbsp;Question">General Question</option>
            <option value="">No subject</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleTextarea">What would you like to say?</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" name="body" value="Body" rows="4" placeholder="I'd like to speak with you about an exciting job opportunity."></textarea> 
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

**Sorry, I meant to say that I also tried the enctype="text/plain", but it still gives me pluses in the body of the email.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spaces converting to '+' from HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857390/spaces-converting-to-from-html-form)

Answer (score 3):

change the enctype attribute in the form tag to text/plain , Like :

```
enctype="text/plain"
```

Comment: Sorry I had forgot to mention, but I had tried the enctype to that, but I still get the +'s.

Comment: well because you want to use html only we are very limited, did you try on other browsers ?